# Remove files from MS Outlook

Tags: email, ms-office, microsoft

A couple months ago I thought I'd switch from Thunderbird to Outlook, I thought it would make sense seeing as I'd started paying for MS Office.

However it reminded me on just how bad Outlook is and I stopped using it a few days later.

Seeing as it downloaded a pretty hefty amount of emails (there didn't appear to be a way to limit the sync like in Thunderbird) I would like to remove any files it generated from my hard drive.

Does anyone know how I can do this? I imagine it is just a case of deleting the necessary file(s) folder(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using MS Outlook 2016. If so, the location of your data will be within your user's *Library* folder.

To view this:

- Go to Finder
- Press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key
- Click on the Go menu and select the *Library* option
- You can let go of the <kbd>option</kbd> key now
- Within the Library folder navigate to the Group Containers folder
- Within the Group Containers folder look for a folder starting with "UB" and ending with .office
- Open this folder and you will see the Outlook folder

Within this folder are located any profiles you created - you can delete these as you wish.

Comment: WARNING: This will delete your entire email setup. I had 5 different google mail accounts setup with specific preferences and had to re-setup everything after deleting this folder - add and authorize each account one at a time and add any custom settings again.

Answer (score 0):

Try `~/Library/Group Containers/`, Microsoft office is wierd like that... it should be in a folder named something like `UBF8T346G9.Office` then inside `/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/` to go straight there, try going to `~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/` alternatively, run the following in terminal: `rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/`[image: directory structure is as follows ~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/]

Comment: WARNING: This will delete your entire email setup. I had 5 different google mail accounts setup with specific preferences and had to re-setup everything after deleting this folder - add and authorize each account one at a time and add any custom settings again.

Comment: sorry @squarecandy totally should have mentioned that in the answer.

Comment: It's ok - if I had read the question more carefully ... it does say "I started using Outlook, hated it, wanted to get rid of it completely". But if you're wanting to continue to use Outlook, but just want to clear some of the bulky cached attachments, this is not the solution for you.

Comment: I suppose that creating a macro would be a more ideal approach for the issue at hand (removing bulky attachments). There seems to be a pretty good guide on macroing [here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-tips-quickly-remove-large-email-attachments-outlook/)

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm

> rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/

was an effective method of freeing up space on my computer and did not harm the Outlook app.

Comment: This purges the cache, but as soon as the person checks outlook, all the space will return. Would you change download headers setting or just hope less mail is on the server after this?